# Why do `scala.collection.mutable.Map`s `withDefaultValue`s not properly retain default values?

Tags: scala, collections, mutable

What is happening here?

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_312).

...

> import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MMap, ListBuffer => MList}
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map=>MMap, ListBuffer=>MList}

> val m = MMap[String, MList[String]]().withDefaultValue(MList[String]())
val m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]] = Map()

> m("a")
val res0: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()

> m("a").addOne("b")
val res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(b)

> m
val res2: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]] = Map()

> m.keys
val res3: Iterable[String] = Set()

> m("a")
val res4: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(b)
```

*some of the text above has been removed for readability*

Comment: Both mutability and `withDefaultValue` are very bad ideas in general, I would recommend for a searching for a different solution to whatever meta-problem lead you to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Because your default value is mutable, you just mutated the default value. But you never inserted anything in the `Map` that is why you don't see anything inside.

`m("a")` is syntactic sugar for `m.apply("a")` which since there is no value for that key, but there is a default value set, it results in the default value you just set earlier.

If you'll check the [`withDefaultValue`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/concurrent/Map.html#withDefaultValue(d:V):scala.collection.mutable.Map%5BK,V%5D) doc, you'll see this:

> The same map with a given default value. Note: The default is only
> used for `apply`. Other methods like `get`, `contains`, `iterator`, `keys`, etc.
> are not affected by `withDefaultValue`. Invoking transformer methods
> (e.g. `map`) will not preserve the default value.

Since `ListBuffer` is mutable you are directly mutating the contents of the default value, when using the `addOne` method on it.

So now every key that has no value in the `Map` will result in `ListBuffer(b)`:

```
scala> m("a")
val res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(b)

scala> m("c")
val res2: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(b)

scala> m("whatever")
val res3: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(b)
```

You should use an immutable `List` as the default value if you want it to remain unchanged.